# Experiencing difficulties handling email intent

Tags: java, android

I have desperately tried all i can to implement email intent on my android app but it still tells me "no app can perform this action". However in my emulator and real device, i have email clients installed. 
I need to know what am doing wrong.

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            email.setType("text/plain");
            email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:example@yahoo.com"));
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Enter Subject Here");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Type your message");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is literally the code that you are executing, your problem is here:

```
email.setData(Uri.parse("mail to"));
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"example@yahoo.com"});
```

Replace those two lines with:

```
email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:example@yahoo.com"));
```

`mail to` is not a valid `Uri`, and `ACTION_SENDTO` is not going to use `EXTRA_EMAIL`.

Comment: i tried ur solution which i have updated in my question above. but it shows me the same error - no apps can perform this action.

Comment: @BenAjax: Perhaps those email clients do not yet have accounts set up. Or, perhaps they do not support ACTION_SENDTO. Your revised code looks​ OK to me.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I had an unnecessary declaration in my code. Thank you

Comment: I have resolved the issue. I had an unnecessary declaration in my code. Thank you